# Custom class names for Material.io components

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-design, frontend

I am implementing Material.io for a web project, and looking to make the class names that are used by Material.io more project related. Currently 'mdc-' is pre-pended to each class and I would like to have this as something a bit more custom to the project. 
*(A simple code comparison added below).*

Taking the Material.io default output of this:

```
<button class="mdc-button">
  <div class="mdc-button__ripple"></div>
  <span class="mdc-button__label">Button</span>
</button>
```

And customising the block element class name to the following: 
*(company used as an example, the desired company name or abbreviation would be used in replace of this)*

```
<button class="company-button">
  <div class="company-button__ripple"></div>
  <span class="company-button__label">Button</span>
</button>
```

Has anyone tried this? I am struggling to find a workaround and it might well be an indication that this is a bad idea.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Its a bad approach to edit the current theme style or make classes just like them, Its good to use your own class with simple and semantic syntax... In above you can use `company-button` and rest styles you can target with them like `.company-button .mdc-button__ripple` or `.mdc-button.company-button .mdc-button__ripple`. Remember to you theme default classes.

Comment: Thanks @Awais I realised the work around and posted my answer below! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes that's what i am talking about Glad that you help yourself CHEERS

Answer (score 0):

Classic case of overthinking, I resolved my issue with a simple extend.

See example below:

```
@import "@material/chips/mdc-chips";

.company-chips {
  @extend .mdc-chips;
}
```